# How to calculate total number of seconds a detected class appear in frame with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, object-detection

I am working on object detection project where my task is calculate for exactly how many seconds particular class was in the frame. I have a csv file of detected classes with their timestamp that looks like this:

[image]

I can input this csv into a pandas dataframe to calculate their timestamp range as `finaltimestamp-intialtimestamp`. But the catch is here is: suppose one class, let say `HP`, made an appearance for `5 seconds`. After that, a new class `kellogs` is introduced and then `HP` reenters the frame.

Following the above `final-intial` logic fails here as there is a time gap after the same class appears again.
How to deal with this in pandas? I'm aware of `.groupby()` and `.valueCounts()` but they can't solve this problem directly.

Example data:

```
           cat           time    
0           HP       06:35:03
1           HP       06:35:04
2         kellogs    06:35:42
3         kellogs    06:35:43
4           HP       06:35:45
```

Expected output

```
          cat       time
0         HP      00:00:03
1       kellogs   00:00:02
```

The output above should return as much time that each class was present in the frame. So in the above example, `HP` has 3 seconds and `kellogs` 2 seconds.

Comment: if you still dont get the problem stament comment down below so i could edit the question according to everyones prefrence

Comment: Could you add some example input data / expected output data that illustrates the problem (e.g., HP appears twice)? That would help with testing a potential solution.

Comment: @Shaido i have updated my answer with one short example i hope you get the insight of prolem statment

Comment: @Manlai A can you fix this

Comment: So HP is 3 because `3 to 4 = 2` and `45 to 45 = 1`, then 2 +1 = 3?

Comment: @Shaido yes Absolutely write i just have to summarize those timestamp to get me exactly how much seconds a class was in frame

Comment: @Shaido if you get the approach pls post it down below

Comment: I added an answer now. I bit late but I hope it still can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating a new column to group by that takes into account both the categorical and time information. First, make sure the dataframe is ordered by time:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.sort_values('time')
```

The wanted column can be created by using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df['group'] = (df['cat'].shift(1) != df['cat']).cumsum()
```

Intermediate result:

```
       cat                time  group
0       HP 2021-12-21 06:35:03      1
1       HP 2021-12-21 06:35:04      1
2  kellogs 2021-12-21 06:35:42      2
3  kellogs 2021-12-21 06:35:43      2
4       HP 2021-12-21 06:35:45      3
```

Now, we can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and compute the number of seconds for each group:

```
df = df.groupby('group').agg( {'cat': 'first', 'time': ['first', 'last']})
df.columns = ["_".join(a) for a in df.columns.to_flat_index()]
df['time'] = df['time_last'] - df['time_first'] + pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
df = df.rename(columns={'cat_first': 'cat'})
```

Finally, we sum up the number of seconds for each category:

```
df = df.groupby('cat')['time'].sum().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
       cat            time
0       HP 0 days 00:00:03
1  kellogs 0 days 00:00:02
```